# Inline::C build failure

Tags: perl, perl-module, nmake, activeperl

I am using active perl 5.14.2. Here I am trying to use a windows C library in my perl code using Inline::C

```
use strict;

use Inline C => DATA =>
           CCFLAGS => '-std:C99 -Tx86-coff -Zi -Ob1 -fp:precise -W1 -Gd -Ze -Go -D_USER_SPACE_' =>
           INC  => '"-ID:\test\incl"' =>
           LIBS => '"-LD:\test\lib" -llib1 -llib2 -llib3 -llib4';


test();

__END__
__C__

#include <incl/hd1.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>

void test(void) {
.........
```

While I am trying to run the script its failing with below error

```
Warning. No Inline C functions bound to Perl in .\test.pl
Check your C function definition(s) for Inline compatibility


Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        C:\Perl5.14\bin\perl.exe C:\Perl5.14\lib\ExtUtils\xsubpp  -typemap "C:\Perl5.14\lib\ExtUtils\typemap"  test_pl_7fbb.xs > test_pl_7fbb.xsc && C:\Perl5.14\bin\perl.exe -M
ExtUtils::Command -e "mv" -- test_pl_7fbb.xsc test_pl_7fbb.c
        cl -c  -I"D:/test" "-ID:\test\incl"  -std:C99 -Tx86-coff -Zi -Ob1 -fp:precise -W1 -Gd -Ze -Go -D_USER_SPACE_ -MD -Zi -DNDEBUG -O1    -DVERSIO
N=\"0.00\"  -DXS_VERSION=\"0.00\"  "-IC:\Perl5.14\lib\CORE"   test_pl_7fbb.c
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.EXE"' : return code '0xc0000135'
Stop.

A problem was encountered while attempting to compile and install your Inline
C code. The command that failed was:
  C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe > out.make 2>&1

The build directory was:
D:\test\_Inline\build\test_pl_7fbb

To debug the problem, cd to the build directory, and inspect the output files.

 at .\test.pl line 0
        ...propagated at C:/Perl5.14/site/lib/Inline/C.pm line 772.
INIT failed--call queue aborted.
PS D:\cmapl_test> perl -v

This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2011, Larry Wall

Binary build 1402 [295342] provided by ActiveState http://www.ActiveState.com
Built Oct  7 2011 15:49:44

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

I tried to build the test_pl_7fbb.c file using the command:

```
cl -c  "-ID:\test" "-ID:\test\include"  -std:C99 -Tx86-coff -Zi -Ob1 -fp:precise -W1 -
Gd -Ze -Go -D_USER_SPACE_  -MD -Zi -DNDEBUG -O1    "-DVERSION=0.00"  
"-DXS_VERSION=0.00"  "-IC:\Perl5.14\lib\CORE"   test_pl_7fbb.c
```

It got completed without error.

My guess the option -I"D:/test" used by Inline while compiling is causing the issue.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: "My guess"? Why guess when you can verify? Do you get the same error when you add that option?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have installed Visual C VC-9 (VS 2008), but last time I used Activeperl's Inline C it required VC-6.

If that's the reason, you could try to install VC 6 or switch to Strawberry Perl which has the gcc 4.6 tool chain included.

Comment: I tried with VC-6 but this is giving more error and most of the options are not available it seems

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing MinGW from ActivePerl's PPM servers. It would probably need a recompile of many of your installed modules to work, but i'm sure it'll make things like Inline::C work properly.